# Widgets don't build when soft keyboard closes

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

First watch [the short video clip of the app](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YVlvBDYB3EQVpwdMVSIvLaAeWK_VeQCE/view?usp=sharing).  Note the photo icon button to the right at the bottom of the sliver app bar.  It shrinks/fades on scroll up, and reverses that on scroll down.  However, note that when I open the keyboard, and then close the keyboard, the photo icon button does not return.  This is because the widgets do not build so the code to calculate the size, opacity and position of that button never runs.  I don't know how I can trigger a build of my widgets when the soft keyboard closes.

Link to video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YVlvBDYB3EQVpwdMVSIvLaAeWK_VeQCE/view?usp=sharing

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TestDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String routeName = '/test-details-screen';

  @override
  _TestDetailsScreenState createState() => _TestDetailsScreenState();
}

class _TestDetailsScreenState extends State<TestDetailsScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(_animationController);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double defaultTopMargin = 190.0 - 4.0;
    double top = defaultTopMargin;

    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      double offset = _scrollController.offset;
      top -= offset;
    }

    if (top <= 75.0 && _animation.isDismissed) {
      _animationController.forward();
    } else if (top >= 75.0 && _animation.isCompleted) {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                floating: false,
                expandedHeight: 190.0,
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                ),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  title: Text(
                    'Add inputs',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  background: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/clouds.jpg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed([
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                            child: Card(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                              elevation: 0,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    TextFormField(
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                        labelText: 'Your text',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TextFormField(
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                        labelText: 'Your text',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                            child: Card(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              ),
                              elevation: 0,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                      child: const Text(
                                        'Additional Details (Optional)',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              border:
                                                  const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                              labelText: 'Your text',
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                            10,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              border:
                                                  const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                              labelText: 'Your text',
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              border:
                                                  const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                              labelText: 'Your text',
                                              hintStyle: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .textTheme
                                                  .caption,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                            10,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            maxLength: 4,
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              border:
                                                  const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                              labelText: 'Your text',
                                              counterText: '',
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            inputFormatters: [
                                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                                  RegExp('[a-zA-Z]'))
                                            ],
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              border:
                                                  const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                              labelText: 'Your text',
                                              counterText: '',
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                            10,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                            child: TextFormField(
                                              keyboardType:
                                                  TextInputType.number,
                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                                border:
                                                    const UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                                labelText: 'Your choices',
                                                labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                  height: 1,
                                                ),
                                                suffix: const Text(
                                                  'Measurement',
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 16,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.archive,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.delete,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              )
            ],
          ),
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return Positioned(
                top: top <= 50 ? 50 : top,
                right: 16.0,
                child: new Transform(
                  transform: new Matrix4.identity()..scale(_animation.value),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Opacity(
                    opacity: _animation.value,
                    child: new FloatingActionButton(
                      elevation: 0,
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      onPressed: () => {},
                      child: new Icon(
                        Icons.photo,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is two things - the widget tree doesn't build when the keyboard closes because nothing references MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets  If you add a reference to this, even to set a variable at the top of the build method, the widget tree rebuilds when the mediaquery's viewInsets change.

However, the next problem is that the scroll controller's offset value stays the same after the keyboard is closed, even though it SHOULD revert back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package to understand if the keyboard is visible or not. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't cover the case when the user closes the keyboard using the bottom soft buttons on the phone.

Comment: You would have to use logic to check that the keyboard is not visible and then set state to trigger the rebuild. The package does not auto rebuild your tree. On Android, if the user taps the soft back button, this package fires false for isKeyboardVisible.